# C++ DES algorithm keeps generating incorrect final block

Tags: c++, openssl, des

I have an assignment for school where I need to use the standard library to program DES in C++. I have most of the algorithm done, however the final block isn't encrypting properly compared to the openssl des-cbc that we are using to verify. The other blocks all work properly, so I think it has something to do with my padding

```
void des::get_mes_data(std::string mes_file){
    std::ifstream mes_in(mes_file, std::ios::binary);
    std::string content;
    std::getline(mes_in, content, std::string::traits_type::to_char_type(std::string::traits_type::eof()));

    //error seems to be here since last block is the only block affected
    if(content.size()%8 != 0) content.append(8-(content.size()%8), 0);
    //end error

    for(char c : content){
        if(c == 0) std::cout<<" NULL "<<std::endl;
        else if( c == EOF) std::cout<<" EOF "<<std::endl;
        else std::cout<<c;
    }
    std::string mes_bin="";
    for(int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++){
        mes_bin += char_to_bin(content[i]);
        if(mes_bin.size() == 64){
            m_mes_data.push_back(mes_bin);
            mes_bin = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to insert an EOF char at the end of content before padding with 0's and I have also tried inserting '\r\n' before padding with 0 as well as per the guide I was using here http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~kant/teaching/hess/krypto-ws2006/des.htm  but everything I have tried doesn't seem to fix it.

Am I missing something when it comes to padding, or is there some special character I need to end my content with before adding 0 (nul) to the end?

Comment: IIRC, OpenSSL uses PKCS #5 padding by default (padding with the bytes that are all equal to the size of the padding, i.e., for 3-byte padding, it uses `03 03 03`).

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question.

Comment: What’s an “EOF char”?

Comment: End Of File, i was using it to confirm the ending characters of the std::string to make sure they were appearing since they don't show on printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Joker_vD for the solution

The issue arose from not padding properly following the openssl PKCS #5(or [PKCS #7 on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7)). By changing the line

```
if(content.size()%8 != 0) content.append(8-(content.size()%8), 0);
```

to

```
if(content.size()%8 != 0) content.append(8-(content.size()%8), 8-content.size()%8);
else content.append(8, 8);
```

The program started to pad properly.